# Extracting value of specific cell and populating it in place of NA values in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am converting a python code to pyspark and here I am trying to use fillna and populate the na values with a value from another column of same dataframe but on index 0

Below is my python code which works properly:

```
df['Parent'].fillna(df.at[0, 'Sequence'], inplace=True)
```

Structure of dataframe before:

```
df:
A       B       Sequence    Parent
QQQ     AAA     0251
WWW     SSS     0616            
EEE     DDD     0720            0616
RRR     FFF     0807            0720
```

Structure of dataframe after:

```
df:
A       B       Sequence    Parent
QQQ     AAA     0251            0251
WWW     SSS     0616            0251
EEE     DDD     0720            0616
RRR     FFF     0807            0720
```

I have tried the following:

```
df.collect()[0]['Sequence'] # This gives different value each time.
df.fillna(df.select("Sequence")[0], subset=['Parent']) # Syntax is not correct
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with collect method but filtering to get the value you want:

```
value = df.filter(df["A"] == "QQQ").collect()[0]['Sequence']
df = df.fillna(value, ["Parent"])
```

Comment: Contents of columns in dataframe are variable and hence they cannot be used for the query. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You only need the firts line of the file. If the file is a .csv you can read the first line directly and get the value. Another option is to convert your pandas dataframe to spark dataframe directly or try with limit in spark but I don't know if it preserve the dataframe order.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to fillna using the minimum value of sequence. Note that Spark has no concept of index, so saying something like `at index 0` is undefined. You need to define an ordering of your dataframe in order for the concept of index to make sense.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.fillna(df.select(F.min("Sequence")).collect()[0][0], subset=['Parent'])
```